# Model data are in Django DB but 'filter' or 'get' not found

Tags: django, model, filter, get

I have 'sqlite3 db' with EmailChecker model with emails which I will check from website.
The problem is that if I insert a new record from django admin, all works ok but if I insert new records from python code, I can view data from django admin (apparently correct) but I can't get data from django view with EmailChecker.object.filter(email=email).

I must say that if I re-save every object from admin panel, EmailChecker.object.filter(email=email) works fine. But I cannot to this because I have a lot of data :(

view code:

```
""" AJAX """
def mail_check(request):
    response_data = {}
    if request.POST:
        em = request.POST.get('email')
        if EmailChecker.objects.filter(email=em).count() > 0:  # if email is in db,    form modal appeared
        email_checker = EmailChecker.objects.filter(email=em)[0]
        response_data['code'] = 1
        response_data['email'] = email_checker.email
        response_data['hotel'] = email_checker.hotel_option
    else:
        response_data['code'] = 0
        response_data['email'] = em
else:
    response_data['code'] = 1
    response_data['email'] = ''
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json')
```

I insert data from django command line with this Python Script:

```
from Timeline.models import EmailChecker
a = open('mail_list','rb')
aux = 0
b = 0
for line in a:
    if aux%3 == 0:
        em = EmailChecker()
        name = line.replace(' ','')
        em.name = name

    elif aux%3 == 1:
         email = line
         em.email = email

    elif aux%3 == 2:
         grupo = line
         em.hotel_option = grupo
         em.invited_by = 'Aitor'
         em.save()
    aux+=1
    b += 1

print 'Total: %s'%(b/3)
```

And data from mail_list file is in this format:

```
name
mail
group
name
mail
group
...
...
...
```

Comment: Your view might be getting cached.

Comment: I set @never_cache decorator in view with any difference.

Comment: I do more tests and I sure that the problem is in Python Script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Resolved. 
I needed to add in each iteration this replacement

```
line = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
```

Comment: Not sure how this resolves the problem. Especially when you say, you can see the data added by the script in admin but not in your view.